# prevent greenDAO inserting duplicate entry

Tags: android, duplicates, greendao

I have an activity that will parse json data and update database using greenDAO once the activity start. It update code is like :

```
exampleDao.insertOrReplace(exampleObj);
```

but when the activity back and resume, it will keep on insert causing duplicate data entry with different primary key but same data, how to prevent duplicate data entry?

Thanks alot

Comment: Please post your real schema (minimum the entity that is to be inserted/updated). It is very important for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you didn't provide a schema or similar information about your data model, this answer is only a guess!

Probably you are using autoincremented primary key.

This means your primary key is probably not included in your JSON data causing the primary key property to be null.

This tells greendao that this is a new entry and greendao will insert a new entry with a new primary key.

Try to read the object first and call then insertOrReplace:

```
Example oldObj;
try {
    // Try to find the Example-Object if it is already existing.
    oldObj = exampleDao.queryBuilder().where(someCondition).unique();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    oldObj = null;
}
if (oldObj == null) {
    oldObj = new Example();
}
// update oldObj with the data from JSON
exampleDao.insertOrReplace(oldObj);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexs for your prompt help, at the end i found out that during the for loop to insertOrReplace(daoObj), i forget to create new DAOobj
for(int i = 0; i< daoList.size();i++){
oldObj = exampleDao.queryBuilder().where(condition).unique();
//this part i forget to recreate new obj
}

Answer (score 2):

Make a column (other from your_Id) unique, and use it as real primary key.

Comment: actually i though id is default created by DAO to be unique, seem not necessary to set the column to unique? i found my mistake, i forget to create new obj during the for loop to insertorreplace the list object to database. thanks

Comment: Great Solution. Simple and elegant. DAO doesn't support Strings as primary key which was my case so I simple add the .unique() to the schema and worked perfectly.

        product.addStringProperty("objectId").unique();

Comment: @Laranjeiro Will the system throw an error while trying to add one with same unique value? or it over writes the existing one?

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @Hiep is in right direction, but is not completely correct: there is no need to change table's primary key.

In fact, it is enough to add `@Unique` annotations on all entity's fields which should be compared for equation, and GreenDao will handle the rest: if the entity you are inserting using `insertOrReplace` is equal on ALL unique fields to some already stored entity, then the old entity will be removed and the new one added.

Please note that this "swap" is effectively an update, but the row ID (primary key) of the "updated" entity will be different (therefore the method is called `insertOrReplace`).

So, given the following entity:

```
@Entity
public static class TestEntity {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @Unique @NotNull private String code;

    @NotNull private String description;

    // constructor and getters/setters here
}
```

The following test passes (you can run it with Robolectric):

```
@Test
public void insertOrReplace_nullRowIdSameUniqueField_existingEntryReplaced() {
    // Arrange
    TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity(null, "code", "old description");
    mDaoSession.getTestEntityDao().insert(testEntity);

    assertThat(mDaoSession.getTestEntityDao().loadAll().size(), is(1)); // assert insertion succeeded

    // Act
    TestEntity testEntityOther = new TestEntity(null, "code", "new description");
    mDaoSession.getTestEntityDao().insertOrReplace(testEntityOther);

    // Assert
    List<TestEntity> testEntityList = mDaoSession.getTestEntityDao().loadAll();

    assertThat(testEntityList.size(), is(1)); // number of entities did not change
    assertEquals(testEntityList.get(0).getCode(), "code"); // same code
    assertEquals(testEntityList.get(0).getDescription(), "new description"); // updated description
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your entity has it's primary key property set (!= null).

Comment: Thanks for reply but i found my mistake is i forget to create new DaoObj in loop while insertOrReplace.